# How can AngularJS have access to axios's result in class controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, axios

So I have a small AngularJS 1.5 app in which I want to put  some  data from JSON file in view  using axios lib and  a ES6 class controller.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('listController', listController)
```

controller's code:

```
class CompanyListController  {
     constructor(){
        this.list = ""
    }
    getList(){
        axios.get("./company.list.json")
        .then((response) => {                   
            this.list = response.data;
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    return  list;
    }  }
```

view:

```
  <div ng-controller = "listController as list">
      <div ng-bind = 'list.getList'></div>
      <div>
        {{ list.getList }}
      </div>
  </div>
```

n-bind in view  gives me  this:

```
getList(){
  return s.a.get("./company.list.json")
  .then(e=>{this.list=e.data,console.log(e)})
  .catch(e=>{console.log(e)}),this.list}
```

which is, I guess, a result of webpack minification. And ng-bind also performs
console.log from  axios which fully logs the result of axios.
`{{ list.getList }}` throws nothing.
*axios* and  *class-controller syntax* are necessarily in  this app.
So Angular does put list's  value (null) in view  but  before axios  changes it.
Can you please explain the proper way to perform that?

Comment: Welcome @Rem. AngularJS has its own http service to perform asynchronous requests. You do not need to add a third-party library to work with the AngularJS framework. You can find more information in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http.

Comment: Im sorry  , sir.  I have to be using   axioss due to  the  task's restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

axios asynchronous requests to server.

```
class CompanyListController  {
     constructor(){
        this.listJson = "";
        this.getList();
    }

    getList(){
        axios.get("./company.list.json")
        .then((response) => {                   
            this.listJson = response.data;
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

html should be like this.

```
 <div ng-controller = "listController as ctr">
  <div ng-bind="ctr.listJson">
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the  response, sir!
Unfortunately  it  remains the same: controller   returns  listJSON's original  empty value before  axios   makes any changes

Comment: you can use $onInit() function in controller class to initialize UI binding.